# install CommandT in OsX mojave . I got Error Vim Command-T plugin error: could not load the C extension

Tags: vim, plugins

Hi I already try every thing but it's still not working

The error said

```
command-t.vim could not load the C extension.
Please see INSTALLATION and TROUBLE-SHOOTING in the help.
Vim Ruby version: 2.6.1-p33
```

As the docuemnnt said I've to use make and here is I try

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/ruby/command-t/ext/command-t
ruby extconf.rb && make
```

I got another error

```
checking for float.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:524:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1144:in `block in find_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1143:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:18:in `header'
    from extconf.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

well after I got this error I try many ways in stackoverflow but It still not working now my ruby version ruby 2.3.7p456  but in my vim ruby version = 2.6

and I try to find error make by sudo find / -name mkmf.log and my mkmf.log in CommandT said

```
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

I spend 5 hr + to look into this but still cant fix =]

Im using mac Mojave last version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also met this problem after I did `brew upgrade` today. I fixed it by following steps:

1. Update command-t fist.

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/
git pull
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

2. Update ruby

```
brew reinstall ruby
```

3. Add ruby into PATH.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

4. Check ruby version is updated to 2.6

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

5. Build commant-t again

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/
rake make
```

Hope those steps could solve your problem.

Comment: Adding `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin` to the beginning of my path seemed to fix this issue for me. Do you know why it might not work with just a stock rbenv ruby path? All else being configured correctly.